# Rails validate based on associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have two classes, Deposit and Bid, which are associated as:

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base 
   belongs_to :deposit
end
```

and

```
class Deposit < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :bids
end
```

The depositions has a fixed amount which is set at creation. The bids also have amounts and I'm trying to use a validation to make sure that bid.amount is smaller than the deposits' amount that it belongs to.

I tried achieving this through:

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :amount, numericality: { only_integer: true, less_than_or_equal_to: self.deposit.amount }
end
```

But it gives me NoMethodError. I also tried using a codeblock but couldn't get that to work either. I'm guessing part of the problem is that the records are not fully created yet but I cannot find any information regarding the problem.

How should this kind validation based on associated record values be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding your own validation method with `validate` (note: singular).

```
class Bid < ActionRecord::Base
  validate :my_thing

  def my_thing
    unless self.my_condition
      errors.add :field, :message
    end
  end
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations

Comment: Thanks! Got the validation working. Cannot upvote because of low rep

Comment: This is fine unless the deposit is updated to a lower amount after the bid is validated. There also needs to be a corresponding validation on deposit so its amount can't be set below its bids. Then if the system needs to be bullet-proof you have to account for race conditions and use transactions.

Answer (score 1):

As [pduersteler says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19629875/2871922) you can use a validation method. Here's the one that would specific to your question:

```
class Bid < ActionRecord::Base
  validates :amount, numericality: { only_integer: true }
  validate :amount_not_more_than_deposit_amount

  def amount_not_more_than_deposit_amount
    if amount > deposit.amount
      errors.add :amount, "cannot be greater than the deposit amount"
    end
  end

end
```

But when you validate on object based on the value in an associated object you must consider what happens if that associated model gets edited. In this case a bid amount should never be greater than the associated deposit amount, but what happens if the deposit that already has bids attached gets edited to a lower amount. ActiveRecord will allow this without any warnings or errors, so to prevent this when validating the `Deposit` you should also validate any associated `Bid`s

```
class Deposit < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :bids
   validate_associated :bids
end
```

This way a deposit who's amount is set below one of its bids will be invalid. This will bring some extra robustness to the app.

The one way this can still fail is with a race condition. The amount of the deposit is being changed at the same time a bid is being created. The validation for `Deposit` checks the bids before the bid has finished being created so it is not accounted for, but the `Bid` is in the process of being created and its validation checks the amount in the `Deposit` before it gets changed. both validations pass then the bid is created and the deposit amount changed to be below that of the new bid, and the invalid state is created with no errors or warnings.

To avoid this you need to put a lock on the relevant record in the `deposits` table while the bid is being created or updated, and conversely you need to put a lock on all the relevant records in the `bids` table while a deposit is being updated.